# Can iOS re-connect to Bluetooth LE peripheral by specifying )CBPeripheral *)peripheral instead of doing retrievePeripherals?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

When I get delegate `didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral`
can I just store peripheral in an array, and then use it to re-connect later, instead of using retrievePeripherals and its subsequent `didRetrievePeripherals`?
Seems like it would be easier, if it's feasible and has no risk.

How much later can `(CBPeripheral *)peripheral` be re-used?  Is it still valid after disconnection with that peripheral?

Workflow:

1. `scanForPeripheralsWithServices()` - to scan for a peripheral
2. `didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral` - when it's detected
    `connectPeripheral:peripheral`
3. `didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral` stopScan and store the `(CBPeripheral *)peripheral` for later.
4. ...  read or write characteristics  ...
5. `cancelPeripheralConnection`
6. `didDisconnectPeripheral`

LATER, TO RE-CONNECT...

1. `connectPeripheral:peripheral` - from array with peripheral
2. `didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral`
   ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES, it will work (but it's terrible practice). The `retrievePeripherals:` method was specifically created so that you can reconnect to peripherals between subsequent launches of an application. You can use your method, but once the app is shutdown, you will never be able to connect to the peripheral again (without putting it into advertising mode and starting from scratch basically). You can store the uuid between launches, but you cannot store a `CBPeripheral` object. So there's the big downside right there.

So to sum up: it will work, but it doesn't really gain you anything. It is not faster than calling `retrievePeripherals:` and then connecting them. Your suggested method is only limiting your abilities for connections in `CoreBluetooth`. But an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, tdevoy.  (Tip one for me when you're in Isla Vista.) So I implemented a retrivePeripherals solution, but it crashes.  Details at:  "iOS Bluetooth retrievePeripherals causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash"  (Watch out for those Santa Barbara girls -- I married one.)

Comment: Hahahahaha hell yeaaaaaaaaa will do...and thats awesome by the way. Feel free to let me know if u have any other probs

Comment: @TommyDevoy based on what can you say that it is not possible to store a CBPeripheral object? From the evidence that I can see my answer would be that: it does not conform to the NSCoding protocol and hence is not possible to save it, it does not have an init method and the key variables are readonly. Correct?